# Bash _/- completion

Tags: bash, autocomplete, readline

`man bash` says:

> completion-map-case (Off)
>
> If set to On, and completion-ignore-case is enabled, readline treats hyphens (-) and underscores (_) as  equivalent  when  performing  case-insensitive filename matching and completion.

```
$ bind -v|grep case
set completion-ignore-case on
set completion-map-case on
```

When I type

```
$ touch _test
$ chmod +x -t<TAB>
```

it completes to

```
$ chmod +x _test
```

But neither

```
$ ./-t<TAB>
$ ls -t<TAB>
```

complete.

Why is that and can it be fixed?

Comment: Try after `shopt -u progcomp`. I don't think that those settings work with the "programmable completion" which is now the default on many systems.

Comment: Thanks! This works for the `ls -t` case but it still does not complete `./-t`

Comment: That seems broken. I suggest you submit a bug report.

Comment: OK I'll run bashbug

Answer (score 1):

Chet Ramey replied to my report:

> Thanks for the report. Those two options work for filename completion, but
> not command completion (the bulk of which is handled outside readline).
> I'll take a look at exposing that functionality outside readline, since
> it's currently part of readline's filename completion, but that will take
> some time and probably require a version bump.